# How to modify Reply To field of an email in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

When user wants to reply on a email that he has received, I want to customize the reply To field in Hybris so that It can be another email instead of the sender's email.
Could any one suggest how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look in your `local.properties`. There I found the following property:

```
# Email address used for replying to emails (mandatory)
mail.replyto=dev@hybris.de
```

Comment: Actually I added an attribute in EmailPageModel that contains the email address used for replying to emails, do you have any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Hhmm, you have an 'EmailService' in Hybris. There you give the 'replyTo' address as an attribute. As far as I know, the current implementation uses the property above for this. When you want to use anoter input for this, you need to find where this service is called and than change the implementaation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite 
`de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.email.impl.DefaultEmailGenerationService#generate`
and create a new method like `de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.email.impl.DefaultEmailGenerationService#createEmailMessage`
that accepts a replyTo address as parameter. Then call your `createEmailMessage` method instead the old one.